# With what packaged foods is there a concern of bishul akum?

Tags: food, hechsher-certification, bishul-akum

I have heard that foods fit for a king's table ("oleh al shulchan melachim") must be bishul yisroel; however, I am wondering to what extent this applies to packaged foods, if at all. Are any packaged foods considered fit for a king's table? What types of packaged foods are those who are makpid on this issue careful to avoid?

Comment: Is this question purely theoretical? Because i would assume that packaged food with a[n acceptable] hechsher does not have this concern.

Comment: @scimonster it makes a big difference. For instance potato chips, the OU says a not royal food and so do not need to be bishul yisroel. Other hechsherim hold that since potatoes are royal food also potato dirivetives need to be bishul yisroel. (This is overly simplifying a subject)

Comment: @Scimonster AFAIK bishul yisroel is not a kashrus concern per se, so wouldn't necessarily be addressed by hescherim.

Comment: It is not clear for me why the link between package food and shulchan melachim must be different from the link between home made food and s.m. because of quality, because of the habit to eat it in all place? Can you explain a little more?

Comment: @SAH, re your comment "AFAIK bishul yisroel is not a kashrus concern per se, so wouldn't necessarily be addressed by hescherim", I don't think that's correct. Anything with a _hechsher_ should not be _bishul akum_ according to that organization's standards. (But check with the organization to be sure.)

Comment: "are those who are makpid on this issue" Everyone is Makpid on this issue. Just because some of the other "XXX-Akum"s (like Pat and Chalav) are subject to disputes, doesn't mean this is too. This is just straight up Halakha and any Hekhsher is taking care of it.

Comment: Good timing on this question. I just read during Yom Tov an interesting article in "Kashrut Currents" which I think is published by the Star-K that discusses if bishul akum is needed for potato chips. I'll have to hunt around a bit, as I'm not sure if this issue is on the web. I am quite certain that it is the most current issue, though. The main question in the article discusses if the way the food is cooked changes the requirement of bishul akum. It has been generally accepted that potatoes are now considered "shulchan hamelech" food. I gather that years ago it wasn't.

Comment: @DanF Would love to see. My community's minhag is to be strict on potato chips, but I think this is unusual

Comment: Canned tuna (or all canned fish?) is also a problem for my community. Needs to be from a heimish brand. Not sure about french fries

Comment: Also canned salmon.